# In iOS 14 Image Picker is not showing images when picking images from Gallery when permission is "Selected Photos"

Tags: ios14, imagepicker

In iOS 14 one of my project is stuck because of its new image access permission. When user permission as "All Photos" every things goes fine. But when user gives permission as "Selected Photos" the app does not shows images thumbnails in list of selected images. Actually images are there but they are blank. I can not find out possible reason of this behaviour of image picker.
I am using swift 4 and ELCImagePicker library for picking images.
What should I do to solve it.??
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**Update :**

PHPickerController do the same thing as ELCImagePicker, it can select more than one pic from gallery.

As a solution I integrated PHPickerController in my app with @available clause. If iOS version is lower UIImagePicker will work if higher then PHPicker will Work.